# Unable To Boot into Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from USB

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb

Okay, I'm a little new to this OS. But, I installed Ubuntu to a usb yesterday. And now today, when I try to boot into it. I get this error "Selected boot device not avaible." then a bunch of F keys are some there. Anybody know what I can do to fix this? I was able to boot into it yesterday after the install.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which mobo do you use ? it must have a select boot device option, like Intel boards used to have F10 or set the boot sequence to removable drives first in bios

for bootable media i suggest dd it works like a charm

```
dd if=/PathToIso/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

replace sdb with your usb drive
then boot into it
format the drive first before using dd remember to use whole drive instead of partition like use sdb instead of sdb1

and if after all your installation done sometimes dd does funny things with partitions,fortunately thats easy to fix too fill it with zero

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

and format the drive ,hope this helps :)

Comment: I now have a different problem, I am stuck in an Login loop with my user and my guest account. Do you have any Idea what to do? I don't quite understand how to use the Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: Its an easy fix http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop  This guy wrote a good answer

Comment: If even that dosen't helps delete this file "$HOME/.profile" by pressing ctrl+alt+F1 at login screen and logging in in command line.

Comment: Do I do: rm HOME/.profile ?

Comment: Nothing that you recommended worked for me, not even the other thread that you recommended to me. Hmm, I might as well just re-install Ubuntu. But thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Sorry i wasn't any help on that matter. But i recommend before re-install do some more digging.